# When should I explicitly add the type annotations in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

> it’s best not to add annotations when the type system would end up inferring the same type anyway.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/basic-types.html

Please give some examples for when to add the type annotation and when not to.
How do I know when Typescript will be able to determine the type on its own?

Comment: This will come with experience. But, for instance, if you set a *new variable* as being equal to one variable previously annotated with `: number` added to another variable previously annotated with `: number` you don't need to annotate the *new variable* with `: number` since TypeScript will have figured that much out.

Comment: Type annotation should be written for function parameters. In most of the other cases, the type is inferred. You can verify what is inferred in your IDE by hovering the variable with the mouse.

Comment: It's always a good idea to activate [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny), so that the compiler will complain if it can't infer the type.

Comment: @georg Please consider writing an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When TS cannot infer a type, it sets it to `any`. There's an option [`noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny), which tells the compiler to warn you about such cases, so that you can see which types are not inferred and annotate them.